# DynamoDB PartiQL Query For Specific Map Element From List

Tags: select, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I have a DynamoDB with data that looks like this:

```
{
  "userId": {
    "S": "someuserID"
  },
  "listOfMaps": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "neededVal": {
            "S": "ThisIsNeeded1"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "1"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "neededVal": {
            "S": "ThisIsNeeded2"
          },
          "id": {
            "S": "2"
          }
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "userName": {
    "S": "someuserName"
  }
}
```

The `listOfMaps` can contain more than just 2 maps, as is denoted by the ellipsis. Is there a PartiQL query I can put together that will let me get the `neededVal` based on the `userId` and the `id` of the item in the map itself?

I know that I can query for the n-th item's `neededVal` like this:

```
SELECT "listOfMaps"[N]."neededVal" 
FROM "table-name" 
WHERE "userId" = 'someuserID'
```

But is it possible to make it do something like this:

```
SELECT "listOfMaps"."neededVal" 
FROM "table-name"
WHERE "userId" = 'someuserID' AND "listOfMaps"."id" = '4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're modeling the one-to-many relationship using a complex attribute (e.g. a list of objects). This is a completely valid approach to modeling one-to-many relationships and is best used when 1) the results data doesn't change (or don't change often) and 2) you don't have any access patterns around the data within the complex attribute.

However, since you *do* want to perform searches based on data within the complex attribute, you'd be better off modeling the data differently.

For example, you might consider modeling results in the user partition with a PK=user_id SK=neededVal#. This would allow you to fetch items by User ID (QUERY where PK=USER#user_id SK begins_with neededVal#).

I don't know the specifics around your access patterns, but can say that you'll need to move results into their own items if you want to support access patterns around the data within your complex attribute.

Comment: I actually did end up restructuring my data to avoid this problem, but I did it a little differently. For the record, I transitioned from using a list of maps to a map of maps and I was able to do this query a lot easier. I pulled the `id` value out of the map and made it into the key value for the new maps. I could then query like this: `SELECT "mapWithData"."N"."neededVal" FROM "some-table" WHERE "userId" = 'someuserID'`

Comment: Glad you got it working for your use case!